# Partial Copy Sandbox Refresh Question

Tags: sandbox-refresh, partial-sandbox

Had a question regarding refreshing a Partial Copy sandbox, was going through the Salesforce documentation for this and was wondering if the Sandbox already exists, do I need to create a Partial Copy template for the data, or I can perform the refresh on the Partial Copy environment and the limited Production data should carry over?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a template to refresh.  From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_templates.htm&type=5), this is what a template is for:

> Sandbox templates allow you to pick specific objects and data to copy to your Full or Partial Copy sandbox to control the size and content of each sandbox. Sandbox templates are only available for use with Full or Partial Copy sandboxes.

Also for your reference, here's the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_refresh.htm&type=5) for refreshes in general.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I should be good then, I was just curious to know what kinda data is carried over and came across templates. Without a template I guess it's sample data from the Production org that is carried over.